# Smoke Simulation not Rotated With Object

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation, animation-nodes

Still working on my movie. I have a part where they are throwing burning pieces of wood at each other and I have the wood all animated and added smoke but noticed that the smoke did not orient itself with the wood's orientation. I'm using 8 subframes and some of the woods movement is animated using Animation Nodes (although turning this off does not set the object to a rotation that would fit the smoke/fire). I have also set the Smoke Flow to come from a vertex group (however the group is fully intact with the model, and when removing it, the problem persists).  Is there some setting I'm missing that has to do with rotation?

Thanks!

Here is a wpi to show what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Apply Scale/Rotation/Location to the smoke domain?

Comment: @RichSedman, Yeah, that didn't seem to change anything. Thanks!

Comment: Ah well, always worth a try. Going to need to provide more info to assist with someone being able to help. It would be useful to see an animation of a few rendered frames to get an idea of how the wood is moving to allow it to be compared to the movement of the smoke. This will help someone to see how it's offset - ie, is it a consistent offset for all or are they simply a frame or two behind. Useful to see the 3d scene to see how the domain relates to the objects. Useful to see smoke settings, compositor nodes, render settings, anything else that might be useful. Could also post blend file.

Comment: @RichSedman Yeah, I ended up making proxy smoke meshes and was baking at 200 resolution for several hours and my computer overheated with only 3 frames left! I even had the case open with an extra fan blowing on it... Thanks for the help.